# Procedure inquiry when using RPMB

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am studying RPMB in Raspberry pi 3B model.
The development environment I have configured is as follows. For reference I tested two eMMC modules.

- Target : Raspberry pi 3B Storage
- Storage

  - eMMC module made by hardkernel

    - eMMC: https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/8gb-emmc-module-xu4-linux/
    - eMMC Reader: https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/emmc-module-reader-board-for-os-upgrade/
  - eMMC module made by uugear

    - https://www.uugear.com/product/raspikey-plug-and-play-emmc-module-for-raspberry-pi/
- firmware: 2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.zip

After the above configuration, the following work was carried out.

```
In ubuntu pc
1. Initialize the partition using fdisk
2. Write firmware image to eMMC.
  - unzip -p 2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/sdd bs=4M conv=fsync
```

After raspbian is written successfully, the partition configuration checked through fdisk is as follows.

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdd: 7.3 GiB, 7818182656 bytes, 15269888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb6b2958f

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1         8192   532479   524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdd2       532480 15269887 14737408    7G 83 Linux
```

After that, I inserted the eMMC module into the sdcard in raspberry pi3 slot and booted it up successfully.
Looking at the log during booting, 512KB of mmcblk0rpmb chardev was recognized as shown below.

```
[    4.853413] mmc0: new high speed MMC card at address 0001
[    4.865921] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 8GTF4R 7.28 GiB
[    4.876187] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 8GTF4R partition 1 4.00 MiB
[    4.888825] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 8GTF4R partition 2 4.00 MiB
[    4.901321] mmcblk0rpmb: mmc0:0001 8GTF4R partition 3 512 KiB, chardev (245:0)
[    4.918023]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    4.943312] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    4.957735] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): write access will be enabled during recovery
```

After I booted, when I checked the device, it was not found in lsblk, but when I searched the /dev directory, rpmb dev was also found.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0  7.3G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0    7G  0 part /
mmcblk0boot0 179:32   0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk0boot1 179:64   0    4M  1 disk

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/mmcblk0*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179,  0 May  7 16:00 /dev/mmcblk0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 32 May  7 16:00 /dev/mmcblk0boot0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 64 May  7 16:00 /dev/mmcblk0boot1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179,  1 May  7 16:00 /dev/mmcblk0p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179,  2 May  7 16:00 /dev/mmcblk0p2
crw------- 1 root root 245,  0 May  7 16:00 /dev/mmcblk0rpmb
```

I installed mmc-utils for RPMB test, and first checked extcsd information.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk0
=============================================
  Extended CSD rev 1.8 (MMC 5.1)
=============================================

Card Supported Command sets [S_CMD_SET: 0x01]
HPI Features [HPI_FEATURE: 0x01]: implementation based on CMD13
Background operations support [BKOPS_SUPPORT: 0x01]
Max Packet Read Cmd [MAX_PACKED_READS: 0x3f]
Max Packet Write Cmd [MAX_PACKED_WRITES: 0x3f]
Data TAG support [DATA_TAG_SUPPORT: 0x01]
Data TAG Unit Size [TAG_UNIT_SIZE: 0x02]
Tag Resources Size [TAG_RES_SIZE: 0x00]
Context Management Capabilities [CONTEXT_CAPABILITIES: 0x05]
Large Unit Size [LARGE_UNIT_SIZE_M1: 0x07]
Extended partition attribute support [EXT_SUPPORT: 0x03]
Generic CMD6 Timer [GENERIC_CMD6_TIME: 0x0a]
Power off notification [POWER_OFF_LONG_TIME: 0x3c]
Cache Size [CACHE_SIZE] is 65536 KiB
Background operations status [BKOPS_STATUS: 0x00]
1st Initialisation Time after programmed sector [INI_TIMEOUT_AP: 0x1e]
Power class for 52MHz, DDR at 3.6V [PWR_CL_DDR_52_360: 0x00]
Power class for 52MHz, DDR at 1.95V [PWR_CL_DDR_52_195: 0x00]
Power class for 200MHz at 3.6V [PWR_CL_200_360: 0x00]
Power class for 200MHz, at 1.95V [PWR_CL_200_195: 0x00]
Minimum Performance for 8bit at 52MHz in DDR mode:
 [MIN_PERF_DDR_W_8_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_DDR_R_8_52: 0x00]
TRIM Multiplier [TRIM_MULT: 0x02]
Secure Feature support [SEC_FEATURE_SUPPORT: 0x55]
Boot Information [BOOT_INFO: 0x07]
 Device supports alternative boot method
 Device supports dual data rate during boot
 Device supports high speed timing during boot
Boot partition size [BOOT_SIZE_MULTI: 0x20]
Access size [ACC_SIZE: 0x07]
High-capacity erase unit size [HC_ERASE_GRP_SIZE: 0x01]
 i.e. 512 KiB
High-capacity erase timeout [ERASE_TIMEOUT_MULT: 0x01]
Reliable write sector count [REL_WR_SEC_C: 0x01]
High-capacity W protect group size [HC_WP_GRP_SIZE: 0x10]
 i.e. 8192 KiB
Sleep current (VCC) [S_C_VCC: 0x07]
Sleep current (VCCQ) [S_C_VCCQ: 0x07]
Sleep/awake timeout [S_A_TIMEOUT: 0x11]
Sector Count [SEC_COUNT: 0x00e90000]
 Device is block-addressed
Minimum Write Performance for 8bit:
 [MIN_PERF_W_8_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_R_8_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_W_8_26_4_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_R_8_26_4_52: 0x00]
Minimum Write Performance for 4bit:
 [MIN_PERF_W_4_26: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_R_4_26: 0x00]
Power classes registers:
 [PWR_CL_26_360: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_52_360: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_26_195: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_52_195: 0x00]
Partition switching timing [PARTITION_SWITCH_TIME: 0x02]
Out-of-interrupt busy timing [OUT_OF_INTERRUPT_TIME: 0x0a]
I/O Driver Strength [DRIVER_STRENGTH: 0x1f]
Card Type [CARD_TYPE: 0x57]
 HS200 Single Data Rate eMMC @200MHz 1.8VI/O
 HS Dual Data Rate eMMC @52MHz 1.8V or 3VI/O
 HS eMMC @52MHz - at rated device voltage(s)
 HS eMMC @26MHz - at rated device voltage(s)
CSD structure version [CSD_STRUCTURE: 0x02]
Command set [CMD_SET: 0x00]
Command set revision [CMD_SET_REV: 0x00]
Power class [POWER_CLASS: 0x00]
High-speed interface timing [HS_TIMING: 0x01]
Erased memory content [ERASED_MEM_CONT: 0x00]
Boot configuration bytes [PARTITION_CONFIG: 0x48]
 Boot Partition 1 enabled
 No access to boot partition
Boot config protection [BOOT_CONFIG_PROT: 0x00]
Boot bus Conditions [BOOT_BUS_CONDITIONS: 0x01]
High-density erase group definition [ERASE_GROUP_DEF: 0x01]
Boot write protection status registers [BOOT_WP_STATUS]: 0x00
Boot Area Write protection [BOOT_WP]: 0x00
 Power ro locking: possible
 Permanent ro locking: possible
 ro lock status: not locked
User area write protection register [USER_WP]: 0x00
FW configuration [FW_CONFIG]: 0x00
RPMB Size [RPMB_SIZE_MULT]: 0x04
Write reliability setting register [WR_REL_SET]: 0x1f
 user area: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 1: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 2: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 3: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 4: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
Write reliability parameter register [WR_REL_PARAM]: 0x14
 Device supports the enhanced def. of reliable write
Enable background operations handshake [BKOPS_EN]: 0x00
H/W reset function [RST_N_FUNCTION]: 0x01
HPI management [HPI_MGMT]: 0x01
Partitioning Support [PARTITIONING_SUPPORT]: 0x07
 Device support partitioning feature
 Device can have enhanced tech.
Max Enhanced Area Size [MAX_ENH_SIZE_MULT]: 0x0001d2
 i.e. 3817472 KiB
Partitions attribute [PARTITIONS_ATTRIBUTE]: 0x00
Partitioning Setting [PARTITION_SETTING_COMPLETED]: 0x00
 Device partition setting NOT complete
General Purpose Partition Size
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_4]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_3]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_2]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_1]: 0x000000
Enhanced User Data Area Size [ENH_SIZE_MULT]: 0x000000
 i.e. 0 KiB
Enhanced User Data Start Address [ENH_START_ADDR]: 0x00000000
 i.e. 0 bytes offset
Bad Block Management mode [SEC_BAD_BLK_MGMNT]: 0x00
Periodic Wake-up [PERIODIC_WAKEUP]: 0x00
Program CID/CSD in DDR mode support [PROGRAM_CID_CSD_DDR_SUPPORT]: 0x01
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[127]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[126]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[125]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[124]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[123]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[122]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[121]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[120]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[119]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[118]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[117]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[116]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[115]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[114]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[113]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[112]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[111]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[110]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[109]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[108]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[107]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[106]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[105]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[104]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[103]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[102]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[101]]: 0x05
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[100]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[99]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[98]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[97]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[96]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[95]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[94]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[93]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[92]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[91]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[90]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[89]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[88]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[87]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[86]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[85]]: 0x01
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[84]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[83]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[82]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[81]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[80]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[79]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[78]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[77]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[76]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[75]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[74]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[73]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[72]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[71]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[70]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[69]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[68]]: 0xc8
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[67]]: 0xc8
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[66]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[65]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[64]]: 0x0f
Native sector size [NATIVE_SECTOR_SIZE]: 0x00
Sector size emulation [USE_NATIVE_SECTOR]: 0x00
Sector size [DATA_SECTOR_SIZE]: 0x00
1st initialization after disabling sector size emulation [INI_TIMEOUT_EMU]: 0x00
Class 6 commands control [CLASS_6_CTRL]: 0x00
Number of addressed group to be Released[DYNCAP_NEEDED]: 0x00
Exception events control [EXCEPTION_EVENTS_CTRL]: 0x0000
Exception events status[EXCEPTION_EVENTS_STATUS]: 0x0000
Extended Partitions Attribute [EXT_PARTITIONS_ATTRIBUTE]: 0x0000
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[51]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[50]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[49]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[48]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[47]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[46]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[45]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[44]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[43]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[42]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[41]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[40]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[39]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[38]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[37]]: 0x00
Packed command status [PACKED_COMMAND_STATUS]: 0x00
Packed command failure index [PACKED_FAILURE_INDEX]: 0x00
Power Off Notification [POWER_OFF_NOTIFICATION]: 0x01
Control to turn the Cache ON/OFF [CACHE_CTRL]: 0x01
eMMC Firmware Version: 
eMMC Life Time Estimation A [EXT_CSD_DEVICE_LIFE_TIME_EST_TYP_A]: 0x01
eMMC Life Time Estimation B [EXT_CSD_DEVICE_LIFE_TIME_EST_TYP_B]: 0x01
eMMC Pre EOL information [EXT_CSD_PRE_EOL_INFO]: 0x01
Command Queue Support [CMDQ_SUPPORT]: 0x01
Command Queue Depth [CMDQ_DEPTH]: 16
Command Enabled [CMDQ_MODE_EN]: 0x00
```

After that, I entered the following command to check the read-counter, but the problem is occurring as follows.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mmc rpmb read-counter /dev/mmcblk0rpmb
RPMB ioctl failed: Connection timed out
```

The dmesg information at this time is as follows.  (Due to the character limit, the middle part is omitted. )

```
[ 1547.320372] sdhost-bcm2835 3f202000.mmc: Card stuck in wrong state! card_busy_detect status: 0xd00
[ 1547.320398] sdhost_busy_irq: intmask 440, data 00000000
[ 1557.600386] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 1557.600403] [5c86e95a] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600414] [5c86e95a] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.600424] [5c86e95a] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600433] [5c86e967] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600443] [5c86e96e] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600452] [5c86e975] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.600463] [5c86e976] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.600473] [5c86e977] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.600482] [5c86e979] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.600491] [5c86e979] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600501] [5c86e97a] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.600510] [5c86e97a] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600519] [5c86e987] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600529] [5c86e98e] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600538] [5c86e996] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.600547] [5c86e996] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.600557] [5c86e997] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.600566] [5c86e999] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.600575] [5c86e999] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600584] [5c86e99a] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.600594] [5c86e99a] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600604] [5c86e9a7] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600613] [5c86e9ae] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600622] [5c86e9bd] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.600632] [5c86e9be] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.600641] [5c86e9be] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.600650] [5c86e9c1] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.600660] [5c86e9c1] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600669] [5c86e9c1] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.600678] [5c86e9c2] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600688] [5c86e9d0] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600697] [5c86e9d7] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600706] [5c86e9de] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.600716] [5c86e9de] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.600726] [5c86e9df] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.600735] [5c86e9e1] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.600745] [5c86e9e2] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600754] [5c86e9e2] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.600763] [5c86e9e2] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600772] [5c86e9f0] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600782] [5c86e9f7] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600791] [5c86ea05] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.600801] [5c86ea06] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.600810] [5c86ea06] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.600819] [5c86ea09] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.600828] [5c86ea09] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600837] [5c86ea0a] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.600846] [5c86ea0a] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600857] [5c86ea17] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600866] [5c86ea1e] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600875] [5c86ea25] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.600885] [5c86ea26] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.600894] [5c86ea26] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.600903] [5c86ea29] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.600913] [5c86ea29] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600922] [5c86ea29] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.600931] [5c86ea2a] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600940] [5c86ea37] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600949] [5c86ea3e] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.600958] [5c86ea4e] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.600968] [5c86ea4e] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.600978] [5c86ea4f] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.600987] [5c86ea51] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.600996] [5c86ea52] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601005] [5c86ea52] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601014] [5c86ea52] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601023] [5c86ea5f] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601032] [5c86ea67] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601042] [5c86ea6e] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601051] [5c86ea6e] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601061] [5c86ea6f] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601070] [5c86ea71] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601079] [5c86ea72] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601088] [5c86ea72] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601098] [5c86ea72] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601107] [5c86ea80] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601117] [5c86ea87] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601126] [5c86ea95] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601135] [5c86ea96] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601145] [5c86ea97] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601154] [5c86ea99] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601163] [5c86ea99] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601172] [5c86ea9a] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601181] [5c86ea9a] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601191] [5c86eaa7] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601200] [5c86eaae] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601209] [5c86eab5] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601218] [5c86eab6] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601228] [5c86eab7] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601238] [5c86eab9] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601247] [5c86eab9] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601256] [5c86eaba] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601265] [5c86eaba] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601274] [5c86eac8] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601283] [5c86eacf] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601293] [5c86eade] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601302] [5c86eade] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601311] [5c86eadf] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601320] [5c86eae1] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601330] [5c86eae2] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601339] [5c86eae2] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601349] [5c86eae2] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601358] [5c86eaf0] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601367] [5c86eaf7] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601377] [5c86eafe] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601386] [5c86eafe] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601395] [5c86eaff] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601404] [5c86eb02] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601414] [5c86eb02] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601423] [5c86eb02] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601432] [5c86eb02] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601441] [5c86eb10] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601450] [5c86eb17] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601460] [5c86eb1e] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601469] [5c86eb1e] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601479] [5c86eb1f] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601489] [5c86eb22] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601498] [5c86eb22] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601507] [5c86eb22] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601516] [5c86eb22] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601525] [5c86eb30] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601534] [5c86eb37] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601543] [5c86eb46] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601553] [5c86eb47] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601562] [5c86eb48] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601571] [5c86eb4a] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601580] [5c86eb4a] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601589] [5c86eb4b] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601600] [5c86eb4b] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601609] [5c86eb58] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601618] [5c86eb5f] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601627] [5c86eb66] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601637] [5c86eb67] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601646] [5c86eb67] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601655] [5c86eb6a] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601665] [5c86eb6a] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601674] [5c86eb6b] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601683] [5c86eb6b] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601692] [5c86eb78] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601701] [5c86eb7f] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601710] [5c86eb8e] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601720] [5c86eb8e] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601730] [5c86eb8f] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601739] [5c86eb91] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601748] [5c86eb92] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601757] [5c86eb92] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601766] [5c86eb92] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601775] [5c86eba0] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601785] [5c86eba7] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601794] [5c86ebae] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601803] [5c86ebae] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601813] [5c86ebaf] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601822] [5c86ebb1] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601831] [5c86ebb2] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601840] [5c86ebb2] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601850] [5c86ebb2] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601859] [5c86ebc0] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601868] [5c86ebc8] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601877] [5c86ebd7] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601887] [5c86ebd7] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601896] [5c86ebd8] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601905] [5c86ebdb] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601914] [5c86ebdb] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601923] [5c86ebdb] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.601932] [5c86ebdc] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601942] [5c86ebe9] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601951] [5c86ebf0] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.601960] [5c86ebf8] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.601969] [5c86ebf8] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.601979] [5c86ebf9] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.601988] [5c86ebfb] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.601998] [5c86ebfb] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602007] [5c86ebfc] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602016] [5c86ebfc] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602025] [5c86ec09] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602034] [5c86ec11] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602044] [5c86ec1f] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602053] [5c86ec20] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602062] [5c86ec20] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602071] [5c86ec23] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602081] [5c86ec23] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602090] [5c86ec23] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602100] [5c86ec24] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602109] [5c86ec31] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602118] [5c86ec38] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602127] [5c86ec40] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602136] [5c86ec40] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602146] [5c86ec41] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602155] [5c86ec43] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602164] [5c86ec44] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602173] [5c86ec44] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602182] [5c86ec44] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602191] [5c86ec52] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602201] [5c86ec59] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602210] [5c86ec68] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602219] [5c86ec68] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602230] [5c86ec69] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602239] [5c86ec6b] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602248] [5c86ec6c] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602257] [5c86ec6c] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602266] [5c86ec6c] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602276] [5c86ec79] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602285] [5c86ec80] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602294] [5c86ec88] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602304] [5c86ec88] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602313] [5c86ec89] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602322] [5c86ec8b] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602332] [5c86ec8b] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602341] [5c86ec8c] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602351] [5c86ec8c] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602360] [5c86ec9a] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602369] [5c86eca1] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602379] [5c86eca8] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602388] [5c86eca8] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602397] [5c86eca9] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602406] [5c86ecab] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602415] [5c86ecac] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602424] [5c86ecac] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602433] [5c86ecac] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602442] [5c86ecba] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602452] [5c86ecc1] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602461] [5c86ecd0] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602470] [5c86ecd0] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602480] [5c86ecd1] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602489] [5c86ecd3] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602499] [5c86ecd4] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602508] [5c86ecd4] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602517] [5c86ecd4] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602526] [5c86ece2] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602536] [5c86ece9] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602545] [5c86ecf0] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602554] [5c86ecf0] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602563] [5c86ecf1] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602572] [5c86ecf4] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602581] [5c86ecf4] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602590] [5c86ecf4] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602600] [5c86ecf4] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602610] [5c86ed02] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602619] [5c86ed09] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602628] [5c86ed20] REQ< 81791b70 10801
[ 1557.602637] [5c86ed21] CMD< d 10000
[ 1557.602647] [5c86ed21] FCM< 81791b70 81791bdc
[ 1557.602656] [5c86ed24] RSP  d00 0
[ 1557.602665] [5c86ed24] FCM> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602674] [5c86ed25] CMD  d 0
[ 1557.602685] [5c86ed25] REQ> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602694] [5c86ed32] TSK< 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602703] [5c86ed3a] TSK> 81791b70 0
[ 1557.602712] [5c86ed59] REQ< 81791c80 10801
[ 1557.602721] [5c86ed59] CMD< 6 3b34801
[ 1557.602731] [5c86ed5a] CMD  6 0
[ 1557.602741] [5c86ed5a] REQ> 81791c80 0
[ 1557.602750] [1c86ed63] IRQ< 440 0
[ 1557.602759] [1c86ed64] IRQB 81791d04 440
[ 1557.602768] [1c86ed6c] IRQ> 40 0
[ 1557.602777] [5d23c9ab] TIM< 0 0
[ 1557.602793] mmc0:>cmd op 6 arg 0x3b34801 flags 0x49d - resp 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000, err -110
[ 1557.602801] mmc0: =========== REGISTER DUMP ===========
[ 1557.602809] mmc0: SDCMD  0x00004806
[ 1557.602816] mmc0: SDARG  0x03b34801
[ 1557.602824] mmc0: SDTOUT 0x017d7840
[ 1557.602832] mmc0: SDCDIV 0x00000006
[ 1557.602839] mmc0: SDRSP0 0xffffffff
[ 1557.602846] mmc0: SDRSP1 0x0000ff7f
[ 1557.602855] mmc0: SDRSP2 0xc3400003
[ 1557.602862] mmc0: SDRSP3 0xffffffff
[ 1557.602870] mmc0: SDHSTS 0x00000040
[ 1557.602877] mmc0: SDVDD  0x00000001
[ 1557.602884] mmc0: SDEDM  0x00010801
[ 1557.602892] mmc0: SDHCFG 0x0000040e
[ 1557.602899] mmc0: SDHBCT 0x00000200
[ 1557.602906] mmc0: SDHBLC 0x00000001
[ 1557.602913] mmc0: ===========================================
[ 1557.604758] sdhost_busy_irq: intmask 440, data 00000000
[ 1567.840437] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
```

I know that RPMB runs in the trustzone zone. I am analyzing optee.
As a result of checking the RPMB-related code in optee, I understand that reading the write counter value should be performed even if the HMAC key is not injected into the eMMC.
(HMAC Key is One Time Programmable, so I am approaching it with caution.)

For reference, the kernel version currently used in raspbian is as follows.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7+ #1457 SMP Tue Sep 28 11:25:31 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have not made any modifications or additions other than the above work. All of the eMMC modules I purchased (hardkernel, uugear) are experiencing the same problem.
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely because the area has not been used - the key has not been written.
Try reading the counter after setting the key with  'mmc rpmb write-key' command ( and yes, this is one-time operation).